# Trouble with local file on HDFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop on AWS with Spark. Running this command:

```
hdfs dfs -put testfile
```

gives me this error:

```
18/08/29 02:59:06 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/ubuntu/testfile._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

and here is the log file:

[Aug 29 03:31 hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ambari.master.com.log](https://github.com/MasterMiror/Hadoop/blob/master/log.txt)

Can someone tell me what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the data node is down.

Comment: namenode jps:14051 Jps
13253 NameNode
13478 SecondaryNameNode

Comment: datanode1 jps:30099 Jps
29909 DataNode

Comment: datanode2 jps:28560 Jps
28387 DataNode

Comment: Was the system running correctly previously? The log file shows 0 DataNodes are running. You might try providing more information to help us help you.

Comment: Run an `hdfs fsck` command, and look at the namenode UI to see what datanodes that it knows about... Just because JPS shows a process doesn't mean their connected to anything

Answer (score 0):

I think it because I forgot to set the Network restriction in AWS' network settings, so datanode cannot connect to namenode. I'm sorry for this foolish mistake to brother you. I changed the network settings yesterday and it worked.